# Let $f$ be continuous. Then $\int_{0}^{x}\left[\int_{0}^{t}f\left(u\right)du\right]dt=\int_{0}^{x}f\left(u\right)\left(x-u\right)du$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then $$\int_{0}^{x}\left[\int_{0}^{t}f\left(u\right)du\right]dt=\int_{0}^{x}f\left(u\right)\left(x-u\right)du$$
Hint: Prove that if $F'(x)=G'(x)\;\;\;\forall x\in \mathbb R$ and there exists $x_0$ such that $F(x_0)=G(x_0)$, then $F(x)=G(x)\;\;\;\forall x\in \mathbb R$

This is a true/false question BTW. I think I managed to solve it, but I completely ignored the hint which is usually a red flag. therefore I need your opinion. My way:

Let $F\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}f\left(u\right)du$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. LHS:
$$\int_{0}^{x}\left[\int_{0}^{t}f\left(u\right)du\right]dt=\int_{0}^{x}F\left(t\right)dt$$
RHS:
$$\int_{0}^{x}f\left(u\right)\left(x-u\right)du\underset{\begin{cases}
a=x-u & b'=f\left(u\right)\\
a'=-1 & b=F\left(u\right)
\end{cases}}{\overset{I.B.P}{=}}F\left(u\right)\left(x-u\right)\biggr|_{0}^{x}+\int_{0}^{x}F\left(u\right)du=$$
$$\left(0-0\right)+\int_{0}^{x}F\left(u\right)du=\int_{0}^{x}F\left(u\right)du$$
Thus RHS=LHS.

$\blacksquare$

My biggest concern was integrating by parts while $x$ is both in the integral itself and in the integral bound. thank you.

Comment: its fine, just suppose that $x$ is an arbitrary constant

Comment: Yeah that should work

Comment: @Masacroso Exactly my thought. It just gets me so confused because the definite integral depends on $x$

Comment: Are you sure F(u) is well defined? What does it mean to take the integral from 0 to u of f(u)du?

Comment: @MathCurious Yes, $f$ is continuous for every $x\in \mathbb R$, thus by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $F$ is differentiable for every $x\in \mathbb R$ , especially for $u$ and $F'(u)=f(u)$

Answer (score 2):

Your method should work, but just for the sake of it here's how I think they wanted you to do it:

Let $F(x) = \int_0^x \int_0^t f(u) du dt, G(x) = \int_0^x f(u) (x-u) du.$ Clearly we must have $F(0) = G(0) = 0.$

By the Leibniz integral rule, we have that $F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[x] \cdot\int_0^t f(u) du\Big|_{t = x} = \int_0^x f(u) du,$ and $G'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[x] \cdot f(u)(x - u)\Big|_{u = x} + \int_0^x \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [f(u)(x-u)] = 0 + \int_0^x f(u) du.$

So, $F(0) = G(0)$ and $F'(x) = G'(x)$ for all $x.$ Notice as well because $f$ is continuous, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus guarantees that $F' = G' = \int_0^x f(u)du$ is continuous, and therefore Riemann integrable, so we can define $F(x) = G(x) = \int_0^x F'(t) dt. \blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for putting it up, unfortunately I'm not familiar with Leibniz integral rule so I wonder how I was supposed to prove $G'(x)=F'(x)$