# Show that $\int _0^x\left[\int _0^tf\left(u\right)du\:\right]dt\:=\:\int _0^x\:\:f\left(u\right)\left(x-u\right)du$ Notation confusion

Tags: integration, notation

Show that $\int _0^x\left[\int _0^tf\left(u\right)du\:\right]dt\:=\:\int _0^x\:\:f\left(u\right)\left(x-u\right)du$ EDIT: (USING integration by parts)

Okay I think I have few ideas how to do this. I am confident that I need to use integration by parts. So $\int \:uv'=uv-\int \:u'v$

Let $u = [\int _0^tf\left(u\right)du \space]$  and $v'$ = 1

Now problem is with the notation and how everything is setup. There are so many variables, the $x$, the $u$ and the $t$.  Now I am very confused how to find $u'$ and $v$. Would $u'$ be $f(t)$ or $f(u)$ or $f(x)$? and same goes with $v$, would this be $t$, $u$ or $x$ and how can you tell and differentiate??

Otherwise I can I can do the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f$ be continuous. Then $\int_{0}^{x}\left[\int_{0}^{t}f\left(u\right)du\right]dt=\int_{0}^{x}f\left(u\right)\left(x-u\right)du$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107044/let-f-be-continuous-then-int-0x-left-int-0tf-leftu-rightdu-rig)

Answer (score 1):

Let $$g(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(u) du \implies g'(t)=f(t)$$
Then $$I(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \left( \int_{0}^{t} f(u) du \right) dt= \int_{0}^{x} g(t). 1 dt$$
Integrate by parts$$I(x)=g(t) t|_{0}^{x}-\int_{0}^{x} g'(t) t dt \implies x \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt-\int_{0}^{x}tf(t) dt dt$$
$$\implies I(x)=\int_{0}^{x} (x-t) f(t) dt.$$

The name of the integration variable is always dummy it could be $t$ or $y$ or $z$.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use integration by parts - this is a simple application of Fubini's theorem, which states that

$$\int_X\left(\int_Yf(x,y) dy\right)dx = \int_Y\left(\int_Xf(x,y) dx\right)dy $$

Here you have two variables - $u$ and $t$, with the limits being$$0\leq t\leq x$$  $$0 \leq u \leq t$$

Suppose $t$ is on the horizontal axis and $u$ is on the vertical axis  - then can you visualise what the region of integration looks like? (It's triangular)

Now, we want to flip the order of integration - as long as we preserve the original region, we can do so. If you followed the above step, you will realise that we can re-write the above region as

$$0 \leq u \leq x$$
$$u \leq t \leq x$$

Hence the integral can be re-written as

$$\int_0^x\left[\int_u^xf(u)dt\right]du$$

Now $f(u)$ does not depend on $t$ hence you can treat it as a constant and get the required expression

Comment: Hi Sreevisan, thanks for your answer, I am just a kid, I have no idea what that is and also my teacher wants me to use integration by parts